# shopify api for page

Tags: node.js, api, shopify

I am having trouble trying to add page by using the shopify api using just node js. it does work without the meta fields but as soon as i try to add metafield it tanks. can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong

const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');

const shopify = new Shopify({

shopName: 'my-store-name',

accessToken: 'access-token'

});

shopify.page

.create({"title":user.title,"body_html":"","published":false,"template_suffix":"Recipies", "metafields": {

"key": "ingredient",

"type": "json",

"value": "{"ingredient":["3 tablespoons finely chopped cilantro, or more to taste","3 tablespoons finely chopped cilantro, or more to taste","anything you want","1 small carrot, peeled"]}",

"namespace": "values"}

})

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it tanks? Can you post any details of errors from the attempt?

Comment: code: 'ERR_NON_2XX_3XX_RESPONSE', it does work and adds the page if i use the same script without the "metafield":"...."

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't figure out a direct way so solved it by creating the page without the metafields and creating metafields in. Then section using id of the page just created.

```
  shopify.page
  .create({"title":user.title,"body_html":"","published":false,
})
  .then((thispage) => {

  console.log(thispage);

  shopify.metafield
  .create({
    key: 'warehouse',
    value: 25,
    value_type: 'integer',
    namespace: 'inventory',
    owner_resource: 'page',
    owner_id: thispage.id
  })
  .then(
    (metafield) => console.log(metafield),
    (err) => console.error(err)
  );
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: Yes this is actually the only way. Metafields can be edited only on already existing resources.